# Pygame mixer clicking sound

Tags: python, macos, audio, pygame, ogg

Okay here's my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init() 
pygame.mixer.init()

track1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("boink.ogg")
track1.play()
```

So I am using a mac and I used homebrew to download the pygame 64 bit version. Everything works well, but when I try to make sounds using the mixer, all that I hear is a clicking sound. Has anyone experienced this in the past that may be able to help?

Also I have tried this with many different ogg files, so it is not something wrong with the sound file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.mixer.init(frequency=22050, size=-16, channels=2, buffer=4096)
song = pygame.mixer.Sound('boink.ogg')
song.play()
time.sleep(song.get_length())
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that and unfortunately had the same problem

Comment: Can you try to reinstall sdl mixer? brew reinstall sdl_mixer --with-libvorbis

Answer (score 0):

Not to sound crude, but have you tried playing a file without using any kind of object? , just play simple sound file and see if it works? I usually start that way.

Here is what I tried as basics (and it works). Do mind, this is on windows as I do not own a MAC, but it will provide insight into if at all file is playing.

Also, try playing different format files (wav , mp3 etc).

```
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('boink.ogg')
pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same click when playing an mp3 with the pygame.mixer.Sound and .play code.

This worked for me:

```py
pygame.mixer.pre_init()

#then instantiate and start your controller

pygame.mixer.init()

#then in your button click or wherever
pygame.mixer.music.load('mysound.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can try:

- Make sure that the path to your sound file is correct.
- Turns out Pygame's `pygame.mixer.Sound()` only accepts Mono WAV sound files.

for my second point, you can go [here](https://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-wav) to convert your ogg file to mono wav files.